# Warning : "Resource.h - not a Microsoft Visual Studio created resource file. Overwrite existing file?"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, resource-editor

Develop environment :

- OS - Windows 7 64bit
- Visual Studio 2010

I created a dialog based MFC Application project using Wizard.
In Resource View, There is a Dialog which is created automatically and is named "IDD_ProjectName_DIALOG"
If I try to save this Dialog, after edit, the following message is occurs

> "Resource.h - not a Microsoft Visual Studio created resource file. Overwrite existing file?"

When overwrite, I can't add event/message handler with Properties window because lists of control event and message is emptied.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I figured out why the lists(which are in Properties window) were emptied.  Because I changed the ID of Dialog.  But still don't know why the message box is shown.

Comment: To save you from panicking in the future, you need to learn, how to write MFC applications without the help of the IDE. Get Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950) to learn, what all the wizard-generated code does.

Comment: You cannot hope to learn using the MFC safely, unless you are **intimately** familiar with the Windows API. This question indicates, that you are trying to learn Windows programming, the MFC, and C++, all at the same time. This isn't going to end well.

Comment: @IInspectable  Thank you for advising and recommending a way to solve it. I'm now learning how to programming in MFC, I wish you would tell what condition affects managing resources. I thought it is important.